# Cant access escalated cases in queue

Tags: workflow, case, sales-cloud

This may seem a simple question, I have a case in a queue as escalated i have full access to the queue, record type ect but i am getting an insufficient privilege message.

I have tried extra sharing rules to no avail and i am able to see the data from the case in a report. anyone that can point me in the right direction will be great.

thanks

Comment: Is the Case View page overridden?